# Animation, I want to alter all the axis at once in the graph editor

Tags: animation, graph-editor, fcurves, axis

Often times in animation, I want to tweak the handles of the curves of an animation in the graph editor to get the tweening effect I want.(I only move the handles on the x axis most of the time, because I just want to tweak timing, not the positions)  problem:  the graph editor has a curve for the x, y, and z axis.  most of the time, I don't want to alter the curves separately, I want to alter them all at once!  is there a way I can do this?  (meaning that when I select a handle for y rotation, it would select the handle for x rotation and z rotation as well.
Hope this was clear.

Comment: I'm not sure it's very clear, could you please show some Graph Editor screenshots with your situation? Maybe what you want is just to switch to Pivot Point > Individual Centers?

Comment: that's not it, suppose i had a cube. and then i made the cube move forward and to the right.  this means that the cube moves on the y axis and the x axis.  now suppose I want to adjust the timing. (say I want to make the cube move slowly at first, faster  in the middle and then slightly slower) this would be done in the graph editor.  so I go into the graph editor, and i move the handles of the keyframes on the x axis on to adjust the timing.  problem:  now the cube has that speed for how it moves to the right, but not for how it moves forward!

Comment: what I want to do, is to be able to move a handle on the x axis, and have this adjust the y axis as well.  I'm not sure if this is possible, but i would like it.

Comment: I'm still not sure, again maybe it would be better to show some screenshots to make it clearer   ;)